# Clojure flatten and laziness

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation, flatten

Not sure what is the behaviour I observe while using flatten when constructing a lazy sequence.

Looking at the source in clojure.core I can see that the flatten function makes a call to filter and hence should return a lazy sequence - I think. And yet  the following snippet gives me a stackoverflow error. In the snippet when the call to flatten is replaced with a call to concat, it works just fine

```
(defn l-f [c]
  (if (nil? c) []
    (lazy-seq  (flatten (cons  [[ :h :j] :a :B] (l-f (rest c))))))) 


    (take 10 (l-f (repeat 2))) is how I invoke it.
```

This is a rather contrived example. Also I am aware that flatten and concat will give me sequences where the nesting levels are different.

I am trying to figure out why flatten seems to break the laziness, even though my (limited) understanding of the code in clojure.core suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laziness only takes you so far - laziness just means that the sequence isn't fully realized at the time that it's created, but building one lazy sequence from another sometimes involves looking ahead a few values. In this case, the implementation of `flatten` doesn't play nicely with the recursive way in which you're calling it.

First, the `flatten` function calls `tree-seq` to do a depth-first traversal of the contents of the collection. In turn, `tree-seq` calls `mapcat` with the provided sequence, which delegates to `apply`, which realizes the first few items in the sequence to determine the arity of the function to invoke. Realizing the first few items in the sequence causes a recursive call to `l-f`, which calls `flatten` on the remaining arguments, and gets stuck in an infinite loop.

In this particular situation, there's no need to call `flatten` recursively, because any call after the first will have no effect. So your function can be fixed by separating out the generation of the lazy sequence from the flattening of it:

```
(defn l-f [c]                                                      
  (letfn [(l-f-seq [x] (if-let [s (seq x)]                         
                         (lazy-seq (cons [[:h :j] :a :B] (l-f-seq (rest s))))
                         []))]                                               
    (flatten (l-f-seq c))))
```